# PHP MongoDB - Retain the array as array not object

Tags: php, mongodb

This is the object which I inserted to mongodb.

```
{
    '_array': [1,2,3],
    '_ass_array': [{'num': 1, 'name': 'One'}], 
    '_obj': {'key': 'val'}
}
```

If I query on terminal, I can get the same as I inserted. But while querying via PHP's `MongoCollection::findOne()/ MongoCollection::find()`, I am getting following format.

```
{
    '_array': { 0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3},
    '_ass_array': {
       0: {'num': 1, 'name': 'One'}
     }, 
    '_obj': {'key': 'val'}
}
```

Is there any way I can get the array as array and object as object? if required, I can update the question with the complete code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the same data this works for me. Just wondering if you are doing something different in a serialization since the JSON syntax in the post. As expected `$data` is a PHP array.

```
<?php

$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbname = 'test';

$m = new Mongo("mongodb://$dbhost");
$db = $m->$dbname;

$col = $db->data;

$data = $col->findOne();

echo json_encode( $data ) . "\n";

?>
```

A little intrigued how you arrived at your result, as various people here have that format in their MongoDB documents.

Comment: @codelover Not seeing how this is in the context of the question, but shouldn't your `Content-Type` be "application/json" as it's kind of been the standard for a while now. It also seems like your pushing this though something **else** maybe, which is resulting in your serialization woes. And perhaps that's another question related to what you are using.

Comment: Thanks. There was an issue in some other module, where it is forcing to convert as OBJECT, there it was using JSON_FORCE_OBJECT hence I got the issue. Which is completely irrelevant to the MongoDB :(. Probably I should delete this question.